# not able to load netflix zuul route values from configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I was trying my hands on `netflix` `zuul` `api gateway` technology. I was able to route my urls using `application.properties` file. But I was not able to do the same with third party configuration using `ZuulProperties`. This is a requirement. How can I do this. I tried below code:

**config class code**

```
package com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ZuulProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ZuulProperties.ZuulRoute;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "zuulConfigProperties")
    @RefreshScope
    @ConfigurationProperties("zuul")
    public ZuulProperties zuulProperties() {
        ZuulProperties.ZuulRoute route = new ZuulProperties.ZuulRoute("http://localhost:8090");// ZuulRoute is static inner class of ZuulProperties
        Map<String,ZuulRoute> map = new HashMap<String,ZuulRoute>();
        map.put("zuul.routes.employee.url", route);
        ZuulProperties props = new ZuulProperties();
        props.setRoutes(map);
        return props;
    }
}
```

here I am expecting that `ZuulProperties` will load the zuul.route property from inside my config class.. am I going wrong? As I had said, I could have done this easily using `applicatin.properties`. But this the requirement where I am stuck. To be frank, I want those properties to be loaded from `database`. But then I came across this piece of code, it was looking promising. But I am not able to do with this.

**main class**

```
package com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.ErrorFilter;
import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.PostFilter;
import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.PreFilter;
import com.example.springbootzuulgatwayproxy.filters.RouteFilter;
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class SpringBootZuulgatwayproxyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootZuulgatwayproxyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public PreFilter preFilter() {
        return new PreFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public PostFilter postFilter() {
        return new PostFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public ErrorFilter errorFilter() {
        return new ErrorFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public RouteFilter routeFilter() {
        return new RouteFilter();
    }
}
```

when I hit `http://localhost:8080/employee/getEmployeeDetails/{employee_name}` url, postman gives me `404` not found error.

Comment: Add `@EnableConfigurationProperties`

Comment: bro, you caught it right, but still getting `404`

Comment: Show ZuulProperties class and your properties file.

Comment: I have only 1 application.properties file with server port key. `ZuulProperties` is a class in zuul api here : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/ZuulProperties.java

Comment: If it is Spring API file, it will be polulated by Spring Boot AutoConfuguration classes. That's why you get all properties in application.properties file. You need to make your own properties class.

Comment: bro I am sure you are a spring expert, but this needs to be addressed by some `netflix zuul` api expert. anyway thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Hi! I have a same problem. Have you figured out how to do this?

Comment: No still not. Still struggling.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @manish no. I am still not able to achieve above said.